# How to make font awesome icons large?

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

how can I make the font awesome icons big as they are in this page:

http://fontawesome.io/icon/bath/

I used the class fa-5x but it wasn't the same as the biggest icon in the page example.

below is the html and css i use, the icon i am trying to make bigger is the bath at the end

thanks

```css
.container-fluid{
    
    height:50%;
}

#run{
    
    background-color:green;
    height:1000px;
    
    
}

.red{
    
    background-color:red;
}

.green{
    
    background-color:green;
}

.blue{
    
    background-color:blue;
}

.reg{
    
    height:400px;
        
    
}

.big{
    height:1000px;
}

.pigi{
    
    color:red;
    font-size:225em;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>example page</title>
    <meta name="description" content="example page">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/tomer/Desktop/test page/first.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/tomer/Desktop/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   
    
    
    </head>
<body>
<!-----navigation bar------->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="" class="navbar-brand">HelloMan</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Page 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eur"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eur"></span></a></li>
        
        </ul>
        
        
        
        </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    </nav>
    
    
    
    
    <!-----end navigation------>
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Example page</h1>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 blue big">
        brushes
        
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 red reg">
        Tishues
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4 green reg">
        Gunners
        
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-bath pigi" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an extra class to your

`<i class="fa fa-example extraClass"></i>`

and on your css:

`.extraClass{ 
     font-size:50px; 
}`

or any size that suits you.

Your question is pretty vague though. 
Better provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: I tried adding another class to the icon, but I managed to make the icon bigger only when added the css inline. any reason why?

Comment: Probably another class has higher priority on the element. Try removing the fa-5x class. If it still doesn't work inspect the element and see which rule really affects it.

Comment: maybe it's because i use the font awesome library font-awesome.min.css ?

Comment: That's the way to do it. Can you provide your code to the original question so I can take a look?

Comment: thanks sakis. I am trying to add the code but it doesn't work

Comment: try to load your stylesheet after loading fontawesome library.

Comment: Thank you! Anytime you encounter bugs like this one always thing about load priority.

Answer (score 1):

Font awesome icons are just same as other fonts, you can apply css to them.

```
.fa-ICON_NAME{
font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This works indeed but by that you are enlarging all icons of that class.

Comment: You are right off-course, it is always good practice to extra class when you are using any framework or plugin. I was just making it simple for him to apply css.

Comment: Yes I was trying to prevent OP from freaking out in case he doesn't know that! You are getting an up vote by me btw,

Comment: thanks it works. by the way, how do you control the size of the icon from the css? <i class="fa fa-bath bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>